# Setting up JVM debugging in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm trying to debug my application that's running on a remote JVM, but I can't manage to get my dependencies there too.

Here are a few things I tried:

#### Remote debugger:

I've set up a remote debugger, and it corrects correctly to the JVM but when I then use my application I get a bunch of `NoClassDefFoundError` errors coming from external libraries that are in my maven dependencies (which makes sense because I building the app with the Intellij building tools and not Maven itself. I have some relocation rules set up so maybe that's the issue?

The JVM itself is running on my local machine.

[image]

#### Maven debugger

There is a maven debugger integrated inside Intellij but it seems like that is just using the remote JVM during the jar packaging but nothing else. Maybe I'm going something wrong there?

I also have a few yaml files in my resources folder that should be correctly included in the debugger.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

Here is my POM file for reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.playbosswar.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>commandtimer</artifactId>
    <name>CommandTimer</name>
    <version>6.0</version>

    <description>Plugin</description>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}_v${project.version}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>/Users/tristan/Documents/minecraft/servers/1.16.5/plugins</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.cryptomorin.xseries</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>me.playbosswar.com</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>papermc</id>
            <url>https://papermc.io/repo/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>placeholderapi</id>
            <url>http://repo.extendedclip.com/content/repositories/placeholderapi/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codemc-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://repo.codemc.io/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.destroystokyo.paper</groupId>
            <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.clip</groupId>
            <artifactId>placeholderapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.9</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.cryptomorin</groupId>
            <artifactId>XSeries</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.minuskube.inv</groupId>
            <artifactId>smart-invs</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.wesjd</groupId>
            <artifactId>anvilgui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the actual error:

[image]

Comment: `I building the app with the Intellij building tools and not Maven itself` if you open project as Maven project in IDE - IDE uses the same dependencies which you declare in Maven pom.xml file. Not sure why and where you are getting `NoClassDefFoundError` errors. Can you add more details about it? Also how do you package and start the remote application? Is it located on different machine than IDE project?

Comment: @Andrey I added more information about the actual error, my POM file and some extra info about the setup

Comment: So do you have the dependency which provides this class added to the module in project which uses it? And you did not provide details about how do you build, package and start the remote application.